# Unable To fetch data from database to script tag while using graph

Tags: php, mysql, graph, charts

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        borderWidth: 0
    }
},

series: [{
    name: 'Not Completed',
    data: [<?php echo json_encode($TotalNotCompleted); ?>]
/* here how to write query to fetch data from database, to make my graph work dynamically */
}, {
    name: 'Completed',
    data: [<?php echo json_encode($TotalCompleted); ?>]
}]
```

Comment: I don't see anything database-related. You should post all the relevant code and values of the variables involved.

Comment: post you database code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        borderWidth: 0
    }
},
series: [
    <?
    $QueryTST=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TotalCounterSales WHERE AdminCity='$City' AND AdminStore='$StoreNo' AND SalesDate='$TodaysDate'");
    while($RowQTST=mysql_fetch_array($QueryTST))
    {
    $ProductNo=$RowQTST['ItemNo'];
        $QueryProductName=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE PId='$ProductNo' ");
        while($RowQPN=mysql_fetch_array($QueryProductName))
        {
            $ProductName=$RowQPN['name'];
        }
    ?>
    { name: "<?echo $ProductName;?>", data: [<?echo $RowQTST['Quantity'];?>]}, 
    <?}?>
]
```