# How to insert MySQL value inside JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a project for our school, and I need a bar chart. I decided to use Morris Js because it has a good sample in the Bootstrap theme which I downloaded. My problem is that I don't know how to get the MySQL values from the database into my JavaScript.

This is the javascript code for the bar-chart:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    Morris.Bar({
    element: 'morris-bar-chart',
    data: [{
        device: 'iPhone',
        geekbench: 136
    }, {
        device: 'iPhone 3G',
        geekbench: 137
    }, {
        device: 'iPhone 3GS',
        geekbench: 275
    }, {
        device: 'iPhone 4',
        geekbench: 380
    }, {
        device: 'iPhone 4S',
        geekbench: 655
    }, {
        device: 'iPhone 5',
        geekbench: 1571
    }],
    xkey: 'device',
    ykeys: ['geekbench'],
    labels: ['Geekbench'],
    barRatio: 0.4,
    xLabelAngle: 35,
    hideHover: 'auto',
    resize: true
 });
 });
 </script>
```

I am new to Morris JS. Please help. Here is what I have tried so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
             // Bar Chart

                             <?php
                            $query = mysql_query("select * from product") or die(mysql_error());
                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                                ?>
Morris.Bar({
    element: 'morris-bar-chart',
    data: [{
        device: <?php echo "'" . $row['product_name'] . "'" . ','; ?>
        geekbench: <?php echo "'" . $row['product_stock'] . "'" ; ?>
    }],
    xkey: 'device',
    ykeys: ['geekbench'],
    labels: ['Geekbench'],
    barRatio: 0.4,
    xLabelAngle: 35,
    hideHover: 'auto',
    resize: true
});
});
<?php }; ?>
    </script>
```

Comment: Where are you connecting to your database?

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29697351/unable-to-fetch-data-from-database-to-script-tag-while-using-graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Morris.Bar({
        element: 'morris-bar-chart',
        data: [
        <?php
        $query = mysql_query("select * from product");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {?>
            {
            device: "<?php echo $row['product_name'];?>",
            geekbench: [<?php echo $row['product_stock'];?>]
            },
        <?}?>
        ],
        xkey: 'device',
        ykeys: ['geekbench'],
        labels: ['Geekbench'],
        barRatio: 0.4,
        xLabelAngle: 35,
        hideHover: 'auto',
        resize: true
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort and reply but when i applied this but this doesnt seem to work it am getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\CapstoneFinal\casas\super_admin\pages\charts\product_stocks.php on line 475, what am i missing?

Comment: already have function at the top anyway and added  }); this at the end seem doesnt work

Comment: something is not closed

Comment: see, i've used the same mechanism to show my charts/graph.. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29697351/unable-to-fetch-data-from-database-to-script-tag-while-using-graph

Comment: Your code worked! Thank you, just added spaces on ends.

Comment: Feeling Relaxed Now @iamnewbie. Atleast, i helped someone.. Thanku.

Answer (score 2):

Once you retrieve values from your database you need to print them from the `PHP` to the `JavaScript` code. The most common way to do this is something like the following:

```
<script>
var valueFromDatabase = <?php echo $value; ?> ;
```

Remember that `PHP` is run on the server side before the `HTML` page is served so what you are doing, inserting `JavaScript` inside a `PHP for-loop` won't work. In fact, I don't think what you have above should run at all because the PHP syntax doesn't make sense.

If you want to print out every value from a PHP database retrieval, you're probably better off using an array in both languages. Then you can print the array out using `PHP's json_encode()`

```
var jArray= <?php echo json_encode($phpArray ); ?>;
```

Also note that you'll need to move the database retrieval results into a PHP array to do so. You haven't done that yet either. You can see an example of doing so in this SO post [retrieve data from db and display it in table in php .. see this code whats wrong with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331353/retrieve-data-from-db-and-display-it-in-table-in-php-see-this-code-whats-wron).