# highchart from mysql with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, highcharts

i trying to create sample highchart from mysql with PHP. i have below codes and it doesnt display the chart...is anything wrong with my codes?
please let me know any solution

created data.php

```
 <?php
 $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','Verizon123');
 mysql_select_db("douresult", $con);
 $result=mysql_query('select * from sales order by id');
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo $row['month'] . "\t" . $row['amount']. "\n";
 }
 ?>
```

created index.php

```
<head>
<meta name="Gopal Joshi" content="Highchart with Mysql" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Highchart with Mysql Database</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/setup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>    
</head>

<body>
<script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="sales" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0  auto">   </div>
   </body>
```

//create setup.js

```
 var chart;
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var cursan = {
chart: {
 renderTo: 'sales',
 defaultSeriesType: 'lines',
 marginRight: 10,
 marginBottom: 20
},
title: {
 text: 'Highchart With Mysql',
},
subtitle: {
 text: 'www.spjoshis.blogspot.com',
},
xAxis: {
 categories: 
 ['Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct','Nov','Dec', 'Jan','Feb', 'Mar']
  },
 yAxis: {
 title: {
 text: 'Average'
 },
 plotLines: [{
 value: 0,
 width: 1,
 color: '#808080'
 }]
 },
 tooltip: {
   crosshairs: true,
            shared: true
},
legend: {
layout: 'vertical',
align: 'right',
verticalAlign: 'top',
x: -10,
y: 30,
borderWidth: 0
},

        plotOptions: {

            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',  
                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 1
                }
            }
        },

     series: [{
   color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
  name: 'Test Colomn',
            marker: {
                fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
                lineWidth: 3,
                lineColor: null // inherit from series
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                rotation: 0,
                color: '#666666',
                align: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: -10,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '9px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
                    textShadow: '0 0 0px black'
                }
            }
   }],
    }

    //Fetch MySql Records
    jQuery.get('js/data.php', null, function(tsv) {
 var lines = [];
 traffic = [];
 try {
 // split the data return into lines and parse them
 tsv = tsv.split(/\n/g);
 jQuery.each(tsv, function(i, line) {
 line = line.split(/\t/);
 date = line[0] ;
 amo=parseFloat(line[1].replace(',', ''));
                                    if (isNaN(amo)) {
                                               amo = null;
                                    }
 traffic.push([
  date,
  amo
 ]);
});
} catch (e) {  }
cursan.series[0].data = traffic;
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(cursan);
});
});
```

Comment: any console errors in your browser?

Comment: We cant access your mysql database, so we would not be able to know, unless there was a public tester url, My guess is that you did not connect properly, when connectinting to the server to check if it was successful use this code

Comment: // Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>

Comment: Wait your whole connect is wrong here is a basic template for it

Comment: <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29697351/unable-to-fetch-data-from-database-to-script-tag-while-using-graph

Comment: connected successfully...still displays blank page

Comment: the graph is shown but the line inside the graph is not showing

Comment: line is invisible...

Comment: check the order in which you are calling scripts .Highcharts.js should be called before setup.js in your index.html

Comment: What your ajax returns and how your data looks like?